# String.FormatException with DateTime in non US Culture

Tags: c#, datetime, culture

I am getting a String.FormatException trying to convert/parse a string when the culture is other than non-US.  The odd thing is that the string was *generated* by applying the very same format and culture as those being used to parse it back into a string.  In the code below, all of these versions will fail:

```cs
const string culture = "ja-JP";
const string format = "dd MMM yyyy"; //error in orignal post included {0:}

CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);

//string toParse = String.Format(info, format, DateTime.Now); //error in original post
string toParse = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Culture format = {0}, Date = {1}", culture, toParse));
try
{
    DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, format, info);
    //DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, format, info, DateTimeStyles.None);
    //DateTime output = Convert.ToDateTime(toParse, info);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The string for `en-US` is `"25 Feb 2010"`.
The string for `ja-JP` is `"25 2 2010"`.

Any idea how to get "25 2 2010" back into a date?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**: I should note that the Japanese culture is hard-coded here only as an example.  I really need this to work with whatever culture is set by the user. What I need is a solution where the date time format works no matter what the user's culture.  I think the single M does it.

**Edit 2**: `M` doesn't work for English.  Anyone know a format string that works for all cultures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change:

```
DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(
    toParse, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

to

```
DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, "dd MMM yyyy", info);
```

the date is correctly parsed.

Note that in your example you are using a culture (ja-JP) to convert to string but another culture to convert from string. Another problem is that `String.Format` accepts a composite format string (`"My string to format - {0:dd MMM yyyy}"`), but `DateTime.ParseExact` is expecting only the date time format.

Comment: If you want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` then yes, you are right. If you use the JP culture however, it is not needed.

Comment: Yes, good catch on the {0:} thing - that wasn't the ultimate problem, but it was an error in my test script (now fixed).  I did also try using the ja-JP culture during parsing - there are a number of tries in there. Only went to Invariant when that wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single M when parsing the date.  That is what is used in the example for the [MonthDayPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthdaypattern.aspx) for Japanese culture.

```
const string format = "{0:dd M yyyy}";
```

Comment: That's really not the problem. The OP is trying to use the composite format string as the format for `DateTime.ParseExact`, which is only expecting the date time format.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "25 2 2009";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d M yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format pattern you pass to `DateTime.ParseExact` has to be just the date pattern, without the placeholder.  And for JP culture, you need to use just one `M` since the dates are represented by numbers even when `MMM` is specified when converting to a string.

```cs
const string culture = "ja-JP";
const string FROM_STRING_FORMAT = "dd M yyyy";
const string TO_STRING_FORMAT = "{0:" + FROM_STRING_FORMAT + "}";
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = info;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);

string toParse = String.Format(info, TO_STRING_FORMAT, DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Culture format = {0}, Date = {1}", culture, toParse));
try
{
    DateTime output = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, FROM_STRING_FORMAT, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: This looks like the answer - does this work for all cultures?

Comment: No, this doesn't work for **English**.  Japanese is a bit unusual where even when you specified `MMM` you get a result that is only `M`.  So the string format `MMM` is not round-trip compliant when using `ParseExact` with Japanese.  The best recommendation I can give you is use the `ParseExact` overload that accepts multiple formats, like this: `DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, new [] { "d M yyyy", "d MMM yyyy"}, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);`

Comment: João Angelo is right in his post.  The real problem with your original is that you're formatting to-string with a specific culture, and then trying to parse it using invariant culture.  The format strings don't match.  If you use the same culture info in both format and parse, it works.