# one culture datetime string to a different culture datetime string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

Running on a da-DK culture thread, this will explode with a "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse( "12/29/2016 4:55:00 PM" );
```

What I would have been expecting was something like "29-12-2016 16:55:00".

**UPDATE**

The system can take a date time value and should be able to parse it back and forth.

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse( "12/29/2016 4:55:00 PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    Console.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + dt );

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo( "en-US" );
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse( "29-12-2016 16:55:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    Console.WriteLine( Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + dt1 );
```

The last Parse is causing an exception, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.FormatException with DateTime in non US Culture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338023/string-formatexception-with-datetime-in-non-us-culture)

Comment: Your exception is cause by parsing with "InvarientCulture".  Needs to be parsed with "da-DK".

Comment: It's really unclear to me what you're trying to do here. What format will you *actually* be receiving the data in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("29-12-2016 16:55:00", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```